# Convert FrameLayout into an Image

Tags: android, textview, android-imageview, android-framelayout

I have a `FrameLayout` which has an `ImageView` as child element. On top of this `ImageView`, I let the user create some texts via `TextView`. It works fine.
But now I wanted to send the `FrameLayout` with its `ImageView` (and its further dynamically added `TextViews`) as a whole image.

How can I do that ?

Here is my XML layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".FirstFragment">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_holding_the_image" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

And here the code to create a simple `TextView` at runtime and placing it on top of the `FrameLayout`'s `ImageView` so that the original image gets "extended" by the `TextView`:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false )

        // put the image into the ImageView via Glide
        Glide.with(requireActivity()).load(R.drawable.my_cup).into(binding.image)

        // create a TextView
        textView = TextView(requireActivity())

        // specify some attributes & tell how it should be laid out 
        textView.apply{
            text = context.getString(R.string.textOnImageView)
            textSize = 24.0f
            id = R.id.myTextView
            layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER)

        }

        // add the TextView to the FrameLayout
        binding.imageContainer.addView(textView)

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }
```

Now when I want to create that "extended" image (original image + TextView), what do I need to do ?

Comment: what do you mean by "Now when I want to create that "extended" image". What are you going to do with this image?

Comment: I want to send it. But to do that I first must have the "new" image with the TextViews on top of it. E.g. imagine an Image Editor where you can write some text over an image.

Comment: You can take the snapshot of the view and send it